# Assistance with MySQL query & timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a query which returns offers for all rows that belong to a club_id that are within a start_date & end_date, however the query should also return results for any that match the club_id AND the end_date is 0 - any ideas of how to do this?
My current query is below...

```
SELECT 
    * , 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( start_date ) AS start_dateStamp, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( end_date ) AS end_dateStamp 
FROM 
    (`offers`) 
WHERE 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `start_date` ) <1329308797 
AND 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `end_date` ) >1329308797 
AND 
    `club_id` =23
```

Comment: What is end_date is 0? Is it '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?

Comment: sorry You are correct Devart - I meant 0000-00-00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `offers`.* ,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( start_date ) AS start_dateStamp, 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( end_date ) AS end_dateStamp 
FROM `offers`
  WHERE  `club_id` =23
  AND (
    (
      `start_date`<FROM_UNIXTIME(1329308797)
       AND `end_date`>FROM_UNIXTIME(1329308797)
    )
    OR `end_date`=FROM_UNIXTIME(0)
  )
```

Please note, that I moved the convertion from unix-timestamp to MySQL-date from the field to the constant - this way it has to be converted only once, and not for all rows. Additionally this way an index can be used.

**Edit**

With "date zero" not being Unix-Zero but MySQL-Zeor the last line should be

```
OR `end_date`='0000-00-00'
```

additionally, if the data type of `start_date` and `end_date` is not `DATETIME` but `DATE` you need

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(...))
```

instead of

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify if `end_date = 0` also reqires `start_date > $timestamp`, so I assumed start_date still has to meet its criteria.

```
SELECT 
  please_name, 
  the_columns, 
  you_want_to_select_seperately,
  for_reasons,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) AS start_dateStamp, 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_date) AS end_dateStamp 
 FROM `offers`
WHERE `club_id` = 23
  AND `start_date`) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1329308797)
  AND (`end_date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1329308797) OR `end_date` = "0000-00-00")
```

Some notes on your SQL:

1. don't use `*` unless you have reasons. which, judging from your original question, you really really don't
2. try to format your code so it's readable
3. sort your conditions so the condition selecting the fewest records (read: has the highest specificity) comes first. This has become more a mental thing than hinting the MySQL optimizer, it's still a convention I'd stick to
4. if you compare (date) ranges, consider using `col BETWEEN min_val and max_val` (boundaries are inclusive)
5. don't use functions in the WHERE and GROUP BY clause. MySQL cannot cache/index these and must thus run the value of every row through that function. UNIX_TIMESTAMP() has a friend named FROM_UNIXTIME() - doing pretty much the exact opposite. This is nothing you can't do yourself in PHP with [date()](http://php.net/date), though.
6. consider setting fields to `NULL` if they have an unknown value. You either have a date (2012-02-15) or you don't (NULL). That would allow your query to simply check `OR end_date IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) AS start_dateStamp
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_date) AS end_dateStamp
FROM
  `offers`
WHERE
  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_date`) < 1329308797 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`end_date`) > 1329308797)
  OR
  (`club_id` = 23 AND `end_date` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```